# python delete folders older than x days

Tags: python, directory, ftp

hy i want to create a python script that is older than x days on a ftp server.

the ftp part i have completed but to delete the folder i dont have a solution can someone assit met with that bellow you can find the code that i have so far.

```
ftp = FTP('ftp.my.webhosting.be')
ftp.login('user@localhost.be', 'xyz')
path = 'Export/XML/Stocks/_PROCESSED'

print('Changing Directory to : ' + path)
ftp.cwd(path)
# List Contents
ftp.dir()

# Get the currecnt time
now = time.time()

# Delete folders older than 5 days

print('Closing FTP connection')
ftp.close()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
#! /usr/bin/python
import time
import ftputil

host = ftputil.FTPHost('ftphost.com', 'username', 'password')
mypath = 'your_path'
now = time.time()
host.chdir(path)
names = host.listdir(host.curdir)
for name in names:
    if host.path.getmtime(name) < (now - (5 * 86400)):
      if host.path.isfile(name):
         host.remove(name)


print 'Closing FTP connection'
host.close()
```

Comment: this would be a good solution if i want to remove a file but in the _PROCESSED folder are only folders stored with date in eg 01-01-2020 02-01-2020... the script should remove the folders and so the contenst of the folder

Answer (score 0):

```
from dateutil import parser

ftp = FTP('ftp.my.webhosting.be')
ftp.login('user@localhost.be', 'xyz')
path = 'Export/XML/Stocks/_PROCESSED'

print('Changing Directory to : ' + path)
ftp.cwd(path)
# List Contents

files = ftp.dir()

# Get the currecnt time
now = time.time()

# Delete folders older than 5 days

for file in files:
    timestamp = ftp.voidcmd(f"MDTM {file}")[4:].strip() # Not sure if correct, but as an indication
    fileTime = parser.parse(timestamp) # you have to double check these, but this would be my approach
    timediff = fileTime - now # Again not sure if this would work, but good approach

    # if (timediff > 5 days):
    #   deletefile()    

print('Closing FTP connection')
ftp.close()
```

This could be an approach, I do not know if this specific code does work since I do not have acces to a FTP server. But this should be a good approach.

Answer (score -1):

found the solution just needed to call rm tree with some additional prams
`host.rmtree(name, ignore_errors=False, onerror=None)`

Comment: This would be a useful comment (er edit) to the answer by@Bob, but it's not an answer to your question about deleting old folders.

Comment: yes it is the code bob provided i have changed a bit , with the additional params you can delete the folder subtree.